# Solving $3\sin(2x+45^\circ)=2\cos(x+135^\circ)$ for $x$ between $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

Please find the value of $x$ in degree from this equation, with explanation
$$3\sin(2x+45^\circ)=2\cos(x+135^\circ)$$
For $x$ between $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$.

Comment: Do you know sin(A+B)=sinAcosB+cosAsinB ? And the one for cos(A+B)=cosAcosB-sinAsinB ?

Comment: Ok i see it on the formula pages in my math book

Comment: And what is the next step ? I really blank about this

Comment: Where you have sin(45) cos(135) etc, substitute the result. The equation should start to look simpler.

Comment: I dont know about it. I confused now. $\sin(45^\circ)=\sqrt{2/4}$ and i do not find the sin(135)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your simplification of
$$3\sin(2x+45^\circ)=2\cos(x+135^\circ)$$
obtaining the left hand side of
$$3\sin2x\cos 45^\circ+3\cos 2x\sin 45^\circ =2\cos x\cos135^\circ-2\sin x\sin135^\circ$$
was very well done.

In fact, $\cos135^\circ=-\cos45^\circ$ and $\sin135^\circ=\sin45^\circ$ and so you can cancel down to
$$3\sin2x+3\cos 2x=-2\cos x-2\sin x$$
Using the double angle formulae you mention gives
$$6\sin x\cos x+6\cos^2 x-3=-2\cos x-2\sin x.$$

Check that you can follow these steps and that should suffice for your tutor until more work has been done on this topic.

Comment: Indeed. I got that far, and stared at it a few more minutes.

Comment: Thanks sir okay.

Comment: Don't you think that there is a problem ? The solutions are just ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from S. Dolan's answer
$$6\sin x\cos x+6\cos^2 x-3=-2\cos x-2\sin x$$ let $c=\cos x$ ans $s=\sin x$ to make
$$6sc+6c^2-3=-2c-2s$$

Solving for $s$ gives $$s=\frac{-6 c^2-2 c+3}{2 (3 c+1)}$$, Square both sides and remember that $c^2+s^2=1$ to get
$$1-c^2=\left(\frac{-6 c^2-2 c+3}{2 (3 c+1)} \right)^2$$ Assuming $3c+1 \neq 0$, cross multiply, expand and simplify to get
$$72 c^4+48 c^3-64 c^2-36 c+5=0$$ which could be solved with (nasty) radicals (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function)).

I wonder if there could be a typo in the problem since the solutions are quite ugly.

Comment: Thank you i will ask my tutor in college, because he giving me such this question, i am just economic faculty student, but why should solve this problem .... thank you so much for your answer, sir.

Comment: @bambangnugroho. You are welcome ! Are you supposed to use numerical methods ? If yes, the problem is easy.

Comment: What is numerical method ? I think this is enough, sir. Maybe the numerical method is okay but your explanation is better than numerical method. I know s and c is abbreviation for sine and cosine. Thank you so much sir

Comment: While fumbling to solve this, and failing, I used desmos to graph both sides of the equation. I hesitated to post such an approach as it, in my opinion, is best used to confirm the answer to this difficult a problem. OTOH, I've seen teachers assign a problem with instructions to "solve graphically on your calculator".